# how to open windows without handles or locks

Tags: windows, uk

some of my smaller top windows can't be opened as there is no handle or lock.
Anyone knows how these can be made to open? How do I remove them in the first place?

A few shots here https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMMzc.jpg

Comment: They look like fixed windows - not mean to be opened. It's pretty hard to convert that type to one that will both open easily and seal well. You might have to start from scratch (and lose the design element in the current ones).

Comment: Thanks folks.. I guess I'll need to refresh these windows at some points.

Answer (score 5):

No hinge amigo. Time to get new windows if you want these to open.

Comment: That looks like a fixed transom window. Light only, unfortunately.